# How to store base 64 decoded image to amazon s3 bucket in php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, xampp

I was trying to store base 64 decoded image to amazon s3 bucket in php here is my code

```
$data = base64_decode($pro_img_nm);
$camp_name = "name";
$bucketName = "bucket";
$file = $camp_name.uniqid().'.png';
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image.png');
 imagepng($image,'folder/'.$file);
$s3->putObjectFile($image, $bucketName, "folder/".$file, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
```

and image getting tored on local because of this (imagepng()) but failed to store on s3 bucket error as "S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file " can anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Check the file name with var_dump($file). Is it at the correct location? Does the user you are running the script with have access to the folder? Is the file there?

Comment: @LajosArpad , the file getting stored on my local folder but failed to store on s3 and here $file is the file name i want to set for image

Comment: Does folder in S3 contain the path?

Comment: yes , I have folder name in my s3 bucket is anything i need to change

Comment: Do you have write access on `folder/` ? Please enable error reporting and utilize `is_writable();` and `file_exists()`.

Comment: @danFromGermany , yes folder having write access. can you help on why i am getting S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file error, is their any thing i need to change on the code

Comment: while i was trying to get the contents of the bucket facing warning as The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, the error is occurred because of the version i used the version we need to use v3 this is the link that we should follow.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/